# JSF/PrimeFaces: Issue in pages with a layout

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I have a problem with my JSF page which uses PrimeFaces components. As it may get long and boring quickly, I try to be as brief as possible. Consider this managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "testBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private String test;

    public String update() {
        test = "Updated.";
        return "test";
    }

    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

Here's the body of `test.xhtml`, with irrelevant content and styles removed:

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout id="layout" fullPage="true">

        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <!-- Does not matter -->
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="input" position="west">
            <p:panel header="">
                <p:tabView>
                    <p:tab title="">
                        <!-- INPUTS and SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </p:panel>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="output" position="center">
            <h:form>
                <p:panel id="display" header="Information">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.test}" />  
                </p:panel>
                <p:separator />
                    <p:commandButton value="Update !" action="#{testBean.update()}" ajax="false" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south">
            <!-- Does not matter -->
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

And everything works fine. I've got two problems though:

1. I should move the `commandButton` to another `layoutUnit` (input) and I can't place the `<h:form>` element in a reasonable position. I tried moving it beside `<p:layout>` so it encloses all layout units but it broke (the updated page no longer has the "Updated." string).
2. I want to perform the update via ajax with the button on another layoutUnit. When I remove the `ajax="false"` attribute from the `commandButton` and set an attribute of `prependId="false"` for the global form element, the output text does not get updated.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: To solve the second problem, I tried removing the form tag completely, and setting the "update" attribute of the commandButton to every combination I could think of, including:
display, output:display, :output:display
and none of them helped.

Comment: :layout:output:display also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I should move the commandButton to another layoutUnit (input) and I can't place the `<h:form>` element in a reasonable position. I tried moving it beside `<p:layout>` so it encloses all layout units but it broke (the updated page no longer has the "Updated." string).*

I'm not sure if I understand your concrete problem. Just do something like this?

```
<p:layoutUnit id="input" position="west">
    <p:panel header="">
        <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="">
                <!-- INPUTS and SUBMIT BUTTON -->
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Update !" action="#{testBean.update}" ajax="false" />
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit id="output" position="center">
    <p:panel id="display" header="Information">  
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.test}" />  
    </p:panel>
    <p:separator />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

---

> *I want to perform the update via ajax with the button on another layoutUnit. When I remove the ajax="false" attribute from the commandButton and set an attribute of prependId="false" for the global form element, the output text does not get updated.*

The `update` ID has to be the relative or absolute client ID. As to how to figure the right client ID, check this answer: [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)

The PrimeFaces layout component isn't a `NamingContainer`, so its ID won't be prepended, and once you take the `<h:form>` out the center layout, then the `<p:panel id="display">` is reachable from the command button by `:display`. Thus, this should do:

```
<p:layoutUnit id="input" position="west">
    <p:panel header="">
        <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="">
                <!-- INPUTS and SUBMIT BUTTON -->
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Update !" action="#{testBean.update}" update=":display" />
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit id="output" position="center">
    <p:panel id="display" header="Information">  
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.test}" />  
    </p:panel>
    <p:separator />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It did the trick. I really don't know why, but I was thinking that the form should enclose the target element as well.